# line 126, in spacy.strings.StringStore.__getitem__ TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, search, spacy

I am getting this error while using this code which uses spacy to search for particular terms in a text file and then add those in a pandas dataframe

```
for ind,match in enumerate(matches):
    for sent in sents:
        if matches[ind][1] < sent.end:
            typematches = findmatch(sent,['Greenfield','greenfield', 'brownfield','Brownfield', 'de-bottlenecking', 'De-bottlenecking'],'Type')
            valuematches = findmatch(sent,['Crore', 'Cr','crore', 'cr'],'Value')
            datematches = findmatch(sent,['2020', '2021','2022', '2023','2024', '2025', 'FY21', 'FY22', 'FY23', 'FY24', 'FY25','FY26'],'Date')
            for match_id , start, end in itertools.zip_longest(typematches, valuematches, datematches):
                string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
                span = doc[start:end]
                capextype = span.text
                allcapex.loc[len(allcapex.index)] = [capextype,'a','a','a','a']
            break
```

After running this code , I am getting this error

```
line 126, in spacy.strings.StringStore.__getitem__ TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Comment: Could you give an example with more details? For example, how are `matches`, `sent`, `findmatch`, `doc`and `span` are defined. Ideally give us a [example]

Comment: Sure , will update the question with the full code soon

Answer (score 0):

`zip_longest` does not do what you think it does.

I assume you want to concatenate the matches, which means you should use `itertools.chain`, not `zip_longest`.

The way you have it now, the variables you're calling `match_id`, `start`, and `end` are actually each a tuple from each of your matches, which is weird and not going to give you meaningful results.

Comment: Okay sir , Can you provide any page link for itertools.chain so that i can learn how to use it and add it to my code

Comment: I tried using itertools.chain , Although that wasn't what i wanted what i wanted is that out of those 3 Matches in for loop i want to correspond them in one row and after that in one dataframe , although itertools.chain made all these matches different

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

Comment: I tried using itertools.chain , Although that wasn't what i wanted what i wanted is that out of those 3 Matches in for loop i want to correspond them in one row and after that in one dataframe , although itertools.chain made all these matches different. Can you help me in this case